# Show error in modal window, when something went wrong

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I need some help. I need to show up the error, when something went wrong in my modal window. Right now, is just closing, also when there are error. I tried to find some Ajax and Javascript to solve the problem, but I can’t get it to work well. Can someone help me and thanks for your help?

```
if($result->num_rows == 0) {
                    $this->errors[] = "User not fund";
                }else{
```

Modal window

```
<!-- Modal -->    
<div class="modal fade" id="resetPassword" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div style="background-color:#3a3a38;" class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 style="color:#fff" class="modal-title">Nulstill adgangskode</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form role="form" action="index.php" method="post">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" 
for="email_forgot">Email</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="email_forgot" 
placeholder="email..." class="form-username form-control" id="form-username">
                                </div>
                                 <input style="margin-left:auto;margin-
right:auto;" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" class="btn-lg btn-
default btn-block" type="submit" value="send" name="forgot">
                            </form>
<?php                                              

if (isset($user)) {
if ($user->errors) {
    foreach ($user->errors as $error) {
        echo  '<a style="color:red">'.$error.'</a>';
    }
}
if ($user->messages) {
    foreach ($user->messages as $message) {
        echo '<span style="color:red">'. $message.'</span>';
    }
}
}
?>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Are you submitting the form on same page of modal  ? (index.php)

Answer (score 0):

Submit the form with ajax and display the error with javascript not with php. Now your page reload and you loss the data.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



$('form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var formData = $("form").serializeArray();

  $.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(data){
      $('body').html('<h1>Thank You</h1>');   
    },
    error:function(){
      $('body').html('<h1>Error</h1>');   
    }  
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two different options when it comes down to posting your data; you could ajax-validate the data (*which means that you'd validate the content in a different file*), or you'd ajax-submit the data (*which means that you'd validate and use the data in a different file*).

I'd suggest ajax-submitting, seeing as that would suit te needs of your form.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var $form = $('#resetPassword form');

    $form.submit(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({

            type:   $form.attr('method'),
            url:    $form.attr('action'),
            data:   $form.serialize(),

            success: function ( response ) {

                if(response != "") {

                    alert("Errors: " + response);

                } else {

                    alert("Password reset!");

                }

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

For it to work you'd have to use the METHOD attribute on the form to point to a processing file, which you'll have to create (*for example; ajax-reset-password.php*). In there just print all errors, if there are any. If no errors occurred, just don't print anything. The javascript above will show the message "Password reset!".